# React-native, android emulator does not highlight inspected elements

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

Today I found out that I cannot solve one of the UI issues, because I could not inspect any element on the screen. I also get "no style" instead of the elements trace.

[image]

(I have tapped on the yellow button above to inspect it, but nothing came up).

Has anyone ever encountered this weird issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution. Turned out, the globally installed react-devtools caused this issue. I had version 2.5.0 installed and then later upgraded to 3.3.2. Earlier today I've switched back to 2.5.0 and everything went back to normal.